# Admob - Not able to show banner in android app

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to check how admob works.

Till time I am done with including admob like this

**Manifest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidbannertutorial"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My XML File**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              >

   <!-- <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4493208dfbf2258768/7749751738 "
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
   ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/> -->


     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**My main activity class**

```
package com.example.androidbannertutorial;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} that embeds an AdView.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  /** The view to show the ad. */
  private AdView adView;

  /* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
  private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-4493sdf352258768/7749751738";

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        /*.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")*/
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.resume();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

**Ques: Why we use this .. ???????**

```
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
```

I have included **google_play_lib** into my app.

I have my addUnitId : **ca-app-pub-4493438885ds9958768/7749751738**

**Here my banner is not shown up within app.**

Only error I am recieving is : **The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.**

Even though I have configured with in app.

Can some one help me out what's I extra need to do ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I am receiving ads after time lapse of 3-4 hours. Can't understand why this behavior occurs ??

Answer (score 0):

Does your code request an Ad? If not then you won't get any ads.

And if you are requesting ads, then you will see evidence of that in the logs as well as the result of the request. Look at your log.

Note also that `android:layout_alignParentBottom` is not valid for a View within a LinearLayout

Comment: Oh yeah .. it seems like I just converted Relative layout to Linear .. But there was no problem with in code .. For some reason Google take some time to update. But that's my assumption.. else app is working great. Thanks for your kind concern. :)

Comment: William kindly let me know if Google does not behaves like this so that I can check with some other problem ?? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your comment, what do you mean "Google takes time to update"? An ad request is a non-local operation, it typically takes5-10 seconds depending on the network connection. Do you have code to request an ad like Ranjith provided? You need that or you will never receive an ad. Are you seeing the ad request and response in the logs?

Comment: Actually I started seeing ads after 3-4 hours I implemedted my code for first time. It is working great as it should work. I am updating my complete set of code including my Activity class. Thanks for your great concern :)

Comment: Kindly check my update and guide me why this happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Can you please let me know why we use this == addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) ... also we define some thing for device ID. ??? Thanks in advance :)